# how to fix this error and why am I getting it?

Tags: c

i need to convert time in 12 hr to the 24 hr format.

ive hardcoded the 12 hour time for now to make stuff simpler.

my logic:
input sting 07:05:45PM
extract last 2 chars.
if AM 
check is first 2 chars are 12.. if yes chance them to 00
else output as it is
if PM 
check if first 2 digits are 12 ..if yes leave as it is
if not then add 12 to first 2 digits

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>

    char* timeConversion(char* s1)
    {
        // input sting 07:05:45PM
        // extract last 2 chars.
        // if AM 
        // check is first 2 chars are 12.. if yes chance them to 00
        // else output as it is
        // if PM 
        // check if first 2 digits are 12 ..if yes leave as it is
        // if not then add 12 to first 2 digits

        char s[strlen(s1) + 1];
        strcpy(s, s1);


        char suffix[3]; // pm am 
        suffix[0] = s[strlen(s) - 2];
        suffix[1] = s[strlen(s) - 1];
        suffix[2] = '\0';

        char xx[3]; // first 2 nos
        xx[0] = s[0];
        xx[1] = s[1];
        xx[2] = '\0';

        s[strlen(s1) - 1] = '\0';
        s[strlen(s1) - 2] = '\0';

         if(strcmp(suffix, "AM") == 0)
        {
            if(strcmp(xx, "12") == 0)
            {
                s[0] = '0';
                s[1] = '0';
                strcpy(s1, s);

             }
             else
            {
                return s1;
            }
        }
        else
        {


            if(strcmp(xx, "12") == 0)
            {
                strcpy(s, s1);
                return s1;
             }
            else
            {
                int n;
                // 01 - 09 
                if(xx[0] == '0')
                {
                    char x = xx[1];
                    n = x - '0';

                    // xx = itoa(n);
                }
                else
                {
                    // 10, 11
                    n = atoi(xx);

                }
                n = n + 12;



                 // itoa(n, xx, 10);
                sprintf(xx, "%d", n); 
                s[0] = xx[0];
                s[1] = xx[1];
            }
        }
        strcpy(s1, s);
        return s1;   
    }  

    int main()
    {
       char *str = "07:05:45PM";
       char *str1 = timeConversion(str);
       printf("%s\n", str1);
       return 0;

    }
```

**Bus error: 10 is what im getting on running the code**

Comment: You are not allowed to change `s1` inside the function as `str` points to a string literal which is a constant. You can try: `char *str = "07:05:45PM";` ==> `char str[] = "07:05:45PM";` but I'm not sure it solves all problems.

Comment: "_ive hardcoded the 12 hour time for now to make stuff simpler._" :  Unfortunately that is exactly what has caused your problem!

Comment: Since I wrote it before the close, you might as well get the benefit, [12 Hour Time to 24 Hour Time](http://susepaste.org/83039052) expires: Tue May 28 15:49:54 CDT 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in

```
 strcpy(s1, s);
```

you're essentially trying to write into a pointer to the first element of a *string literal*. It invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Check the function call

```
timeConversion(str);
```

where `str` points to a *string literal*, and any attempt to modify the contents of a *string literal* is UB.

What you need to do in `timeConversion()` function is to:

- have required amount of memory allocated (call to `malloc()` is one way)
- use that to hold the modified output
- return the pointer to the caller.
- free the memory once you're done using it.